# Flutter: DatePicker not picking the selected date

Tags: android, flutter, dart, datepicker

I am building a personal expenses app using flutter. I open modal sheet whereby I enter my new transactions for a particular expense. In that modal sheet I use showDatePicker() to open a calendar to pick my date. The issue I am facing is that when I open the sheet, initially it shows No date chosen and when I choose a date it displays the date I have chosen but when I click on the add transaction button so I can display the same in a customized list, the date shown is of the present i.e. DateTime.now() instead of the one I have picked.

The following is the code for adding a new transaction:

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function addTx;

  NewTransaction(this.addTx);

  @override
  State<NewTransaction> createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);

    if (enteredTitle.isEmpty || enteredAmount <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    widget.addTx(
      enteredTitle,
      enteredAmount,
    );

    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // closes the top most screen that is opened
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime(2022),
            lastDate: DateTime.now())
        .then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: _titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
              // onChanged: (val) {
              //   titleInput = val;
              // },
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              controller: _amountController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
              // onChanged: (val) {
              //   amountInput = val;
              // },
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70,
              child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    _selectedDate == null
                        ? 'No Date Chosen'
                        : "Picked Date: ${DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!)}",
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  child: const Text("Choose Date",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
                )
              ]),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Add Transaction'),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.color,
              onPressed: _submitData,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to parse _selectedDate variable into addTx function to access the value on the parent screen.

```
widget.addTx(
  enteredTitle,
  enteredAmount,
  _selectedDate
);
```

because your _selectedDate variable is your local variable.

Comment: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction'
Receiver: Closure: (String, double) => void from Function '_addNewTransaction@18232360':.
Tried calling: _MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction("Clothes ", 25.64, Instance of 'DateTime')
Found: _MyHomePageState._addNewTransaction(String, double) => void



This is the error I get on the console after doing so

Comment: You also need to define the DateTime argument on your function where you are using it like (String, double, DateTime) => Function addTx because it has only Two arguments